# c# property SetValue - doesn't take effect in binded controls

Tags: c#, reflection, binding

I used reflection for changing property. Something like this:

```
if (obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null)
{
   obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(obj, value,null);

   return true;`enter code here`
}
```

The problem is, that I am using binding and I have binded controls to this changed object properties. If I change property value by calling SetValue property change correctly, but it doesn't take effect on e.g. textbox binded on this property.

Does someone know how can I solve this problem?

Here is code how am I binding controls:

```
((Control)comp).DataBindings.Add(new Binding(comp._BindingProperty.ToString(), comp.Unit.Data, comp._DbField,true));
```

Comment: You need to invoke the `OnPropertyChanged` method to notify bound controls, I think.

Comment: **Why** are you using reflection?

Comment: @MarioStoilov is right, Skliwz as well. `OnPropertyChanged` is your best friend when it comes to binding.

Comment: Does your type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or any kind of change notifications?

Comment: Hi Sriram, unfortunately no. This is entity generated by EF edmx model. Is it just structure which is not derived from any other class.

Comment: You shouldn't bind directly to a class form the EF, you should use a ViewModel class (lookup MVVM, Model-View-ViewModel)

Comment: Well this is winforms app and as I heard MVVM is not very suitable for this kind of apps. But I am new in EF, so maybe I am just confused.

Comment: So, guys what are you suggesting for me ... I can't give up from reflection, because it is hardly abstract method and I don't have exact object here.

I am just a begginer in WinForms, EF and binding. Can someone suggest to me some good article or key word for which I should be looking?

Thx